# Routing VLAN out to internet on a Cisco 3750G

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, vlan, firewall

I have a WAN port (firewall, 192.168.70.1/24) plugged into port 24 of a Cisco 3750G.

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
  no switchport
  ip address 192.168.70.2 255.255.255.0
```

I have my default route going out this port.

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.70.1
```

I can get out to the internet from the switch.

I have a computer (192.168.71.201/24 GW .1) plugged into port 1, vlan 71:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  switchport access vlan 71
  switchport mode access

interface Vlan71
  ip address 192.168.71.1 255.255.255.0
```

The computer can ping the `71.1` gateway, however can't get to the internet via `70.1`.

How do I route this out?

---

```
Full Switch Config:

version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname pac-inet-cs1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 xxx
enable password xxx
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
switch 1 provision ws-c3750g-24t
system mtu routing 1500
authentication mac-move permit
ip subnet-zero
ip routing
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 4.4.4.4
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-231101568
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-231101568
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-231101568
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-231101568
 certificate self-signed 01
 xxx
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree etherchannel guard misconfig
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 switchport access vlan 71
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 switchport access vlan 71
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/13
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
 no switchport
 ip address 192.168.70.2 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan71
 description Spectrum Public
 ip address 192.168.71.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.70.1
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
!
ip sla enable reaction-alerts
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 password xxx
 login
line vty 5 15
 password xxx
 login
!
end
```

Comment: You need to post the full switch configuration.

Comment: OK, but what is the firewall model and configuration? It is likely that the firewall is not doing NAT for the user VLAN, or there is some other problem with it if the PC can ping the firewall interface.

Comment: It's a PFSense, so not sure how to dump config for you. FTR, I can browse to the PFSense's web UI from the `71` network.

Comment: You need to use the shell to dump the configuration. There are instructions on the pfSense site.

Comment: Okay. It's a brand new box, if that matters. i.e. I've configure basically nothing on it, besides adding this route and configuring the WAN.

Comment: You are using private addressing on your LAN, and you need to set up NAT to translate the private LAN addressing to the public Internet address. The switch configuration looks good now, but you seem to have a firewall problem. Is there anyone else in your business that knows more about this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! But the odd thing is that if I plug a laptop directly into LAN on the PFsense, set a `70.x` address with `70.1` as the gateway, I can get out fine. In other words from `70` on out, there's no problem so I'm not sure what to change on the NATing.. .

Comment: Your firewall is automatically using NAT on its directly connected network, but not on a network that is not directly connected. You need to configure that.

Comment: Gotcha. Okay I checked and the auto-generate NAT rules seemed to cover this: `127.0.0.0/8 192.168.71.0/24 192.168.70.0/24 => WAN Address`. It guess it figured this out from the route I added. (Your patience is appreciated!)

Comment: Okay nailed it. Firewall wasn't allowing outbound from other subnets than `70`. It's working now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One likely problem is that you have not enabled routing on the switch. This is very common. You need to make sure that you enable routing from the global configuration mode:

```
ip routing
```

Also, your firewall needs to know to send traffic destined to the `192.168.71.0/24` network to the switch. Unless you have a static route in the firewall or you are running a common routing protocol between the firewall and the switch, the firewall has no way to know to send that traffic to the switch, so it will send the traffic to its default route (the Internet connection).

Comment: Ah! The route back seems to be what I was missing, thanks. Trying it now.

Comment: Okay, IP routing is enabled, `70.1` can ping the client (`71.50`) and the client can ping `70.1`. However, the client still doesn't find a route out to the internet with its gateway set to `71.1`. What am I missing?

Comment: You are going to need to give us full configurations of the firewall and switch.

Comment: Okay, added switch config. Firewall is a PFSense, but I added a route to `192.168.71.0/24` through `192.168.70.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly enable "  ip routing" command in layer3 switch

Further configure default route in firewall

**In firewall**

`Firewall(config)# ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 ISP gateway`

Pointing towards gateway for ISP

And specific route in firewall

Firewall(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.70.2

**In core switch 3750G**

Configure default route gateway pointing towards firewall interfàce that is 192.168.70.1

`Switch(config)# ip route 192.168.71.255.255.255.0  192.168.70.1`

Answer (score -1):

traceroute to a internet address. See which route its taking. Make sure its hitting your next hop. Once you find the last hop you can start looking there.

Comment: It hits `192.168.71.1` (Layer 3 switch) and then dies.

Comment: Do a show ip route "internet address" from your layer 3 switch to see if the route is good.